# Converting a list of tuples to an array or other structure that allows easy slicing

Tags: python

Using list comprehension I have created a list of tuples which looks like

```
temp = [(1, 0, 1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1, 0, 5), (1, 0, 2, 0, 2), (1, 0, 2, 0, 5)]
```

I could also create a list of lists if that works easier.

Either way, I would now like to get an array, or a 2D list, from the data. Something where I can easily access the value of the first element in each tuple in the above using slicing, something like

```
first_elements = temp[:,0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) for that type of indexing:

```
import numpy as np
temp = [(1, 0, 1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1, 0, 5), (1, 0, 2, 0, 2), (1, 0, 2, 0, 5)]

a = np.array(temp)
a[:, 0]
```

returns

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

**Note**: all of your inner lists must be of the same size at for this to work. Otherwise the array constructor will return an array of Python lists.

Comment: That was embarrassingly straight forward. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` and `next` to get what you want:

```
temp = [(1, 0, 1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1, 0, 5), (1, 0, 2, 0, 2), (1, 0, 2, 0, 5)]
print(next(zip(*temp)))
```

Returns:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: nice. Note that python 2 `zip` is not so good as it returns a `list`. In that case `itertools.izip` would be better.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Python 3, so this answer works great

Comment: the crime would be to answer for python 2 only. this answer is valid, albeit not optimal in python 2 but who cares? (and doesn't need the `numpy` bazooka)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) which allows you to fetch different combinations from you existing data-structure

For example to fetch first element of each `tuple` use:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> temp = [(1, 0, 1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 1, 0, 5), (1, 0, 2, 0, 2), (1, 0, 2, 0, 5)]
>>> list(map(itemgetter(0),temp))
>>> [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

To fetch second element

```
 >>> list(map(itemgetter(1),temp))
 >>> [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To fetch first and second

```
 >>> list(map(itemgetter(0,1),temp))
 >>> [(1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]
```